# Nesting dependentObservable doesn't seem to work in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a dependentObservable bound to a div on my page - it concatenates the values of one other depedentObservable and one '.subscribe method' like this:

```
this.previewText = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    return this.myDependentObservable() + this.mySubscribeMethod();
}, this);
```

This seems to work fine when for anything in 'mySubscribedMethod', but the value of 'myDependentObservable' is never changed.

I have set a breakpoint in myDependentObservable and can see that it is only run once when the viewmodel is applied. It is not run when other observables change values.

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved:

It turns out you CAN nest dependentObservables. However, you need make sure whatever observables your dependentObservable is depending on has been defined prior to your dependentObservable definition.